# Why i need to create a Bean of SpringApplicationContext?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Code 1 Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MobileAppWsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MobileAppWsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Code 2 ApplicationContext

```
public class SpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;
    
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CONTEXT = applicationContext;
    }
    
    public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
        return CONTEXT.getBean(beanName);
    }

}
```

Code 3 service class

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
..............
}
```

Code 4

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
......
......
@Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
..............
UserService userService =(UserService)SpringApplicationContext
                                    .getBean("userServiceImpl"); // this line throws error
..............
     }
}
```

As AuthenticationFilter  cannot access service class directly by autowiring so i am using SpringApplicationContext for it .However it shows an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.haider.app.ws.SpringApplicationContext.getBean(SpringApplicationContext.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.haider.app.ws.security.AuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(AuthenticationFilter.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar:5.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.17.RELEASE.jar:5.1.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

However it get resolved after i changed the main class to

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MobileAppWsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MobileAppWsApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public SpringApplicationContext springApplicationContext() {
        return new SpringApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

So why do i need to create a bean for SpringApplicationContext  why i cannot use it directly as it invokes static method. Also is there any other way to do so ( I am using Java based annotation for beans not xml).

Answer (score 1):

You need to register `SpringApplicationContext` as spring bean, in order to have callback method `setApplicationContext` from `ApplicationContextAware` interface invoked by spring. Without it `SpringApplicationContext.CONTEXT` will not be initialized, and hence will be null.
In order to register spring bean even simpler you can just add `@Component` or `@Service` annotation on the class (i.e. on `SpringApplicationContext`)

In fact you don't really need class like `SpringApplicationContext` and you shouldn't use such holder class. You can register `AuthenticationFilter` as spring bean and inject there `UserService`

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    
    private final UserService userService;

    public AuthenticationFilter(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService; 
    }

    .......

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        userService.someMethod()
    }
}
```